# Return an Array of Strings from an ASP.NET Web Service to an Android client using SOAP

Tags: android, asp.net, vb.net, web-services, soap

I want to return an array of strings to my Android client and populate a ListView.
I am using the SOAP library (org.ksoap2.*) to invoke an ASP.NET web service.

Here is the code for the web service:

**1. ASP Web Service**

```
    Imports ...
    Imports System.Web.Services
    Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
    Imports ...

    <WebService(Namespace:="...")>_
    <WebService(ConformsTo:=...)> _
    <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _

    Public Class EnquiryWS
        Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    ' Web method
           <WebMethod()> _
           Public Function GetList() As String()
                  'Hardcoded list
                  Return New String() { "item1", "item2", "item3" }
           End Function
```

I've tested the web service by accessing the asmx, there are no runtime errors.
I've also tested it with just a simple string, the web service returned the string to Android.  Like this:

```
    ' Web method
    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetString() As String
           Return "My string."
    End Function
```

**2. Android Activity**

Secondly, here is my Android code that is invoking the ASP.NET web service.

```
    import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

           private ArrayList<String> list;
           private ListView listview;
           private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                     //...
                     new GetPersonList().execute("AsyncTask String");
                     //...
           }

           // Inner AsyncTask class
           private class GetPersonList extends AsyncTask<String,  Integer,String> {
                   private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "https://myNamespace/GetList";
                   private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetList";
                   private static final String NAMESPACE = "https://myNamespace/";
                   private static final String URL =
            "https://myIISsite/myASMXfile.asmx";

                   @Override
                   protected void onPreExecute() {
                             super.onPreExecute();
                             // onPreExecute stuff
                   }

                   @Override
                   protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
                             String result = null;

                             SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                             //Create envelope
                             SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                             //Required for .net
                             envelope.dotNet = true;

                             //Set output SOAP object
                             envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                             //Create HTTP call object
                             HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                             try {
                                  //Invoke web service
                                  androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                                  //Get the response
                                  SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                                  //Assign it to response to a static variable
                                  result = response.toString();
                             } catch (Exception e) {
                                  result = "error " + e.getMessage();
                             }

                             return result;
                   }

                   @Override
                   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                             System.out.println("Returned SOAP XML: " + result);
                             MyFunction(result);
                   }
           }
    }
```

MyFunction is a method that I created to do some additional work.

**3. MyFunction**

Here is MyFunction method code:

```
    public void MyFunction(String s) {
           // Add Webservice response to list
           list.add(s);

           // Set adapter
           adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item1, list);
           listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

The argument I pass to MyFunction is the SOAP response, I then add it to the list and set the adapter.

Okay, so the web service is returning an array of strings, but the **overriden** onPostExecute method is working with one string, if I declare the onPostExecute parameter as a Collection, it is obviously not overriding anymore.

This is the error that I am getting in logcat:

```
    Return SOAP XML: error expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <html>@1:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4182d238)
```

Could anyone please advise?

Comment: It is not necessary for you to return result from doInBackground to onPostExecute(). You can define a global string[] which you can use to get result in doInBackground() and then do with that string[] in onPostExecute method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.  I am casting the response as a SoapObject and not as a SoapPrimitive, the reason for that is because a SoapPrimitive is for primitive data types, SoapObject supports composite data types.  Therefore, I am casting my array as a SoapObject and not as a SoapPrimitive anymore.

I have removed the MyFunction() method, because I am setting the adapter in the onPostExecute() method by override run().  And finally, I have added a ProgressDialog, I am showing the ProgressDialog in the onPreExecute() method while it's processing, and then I am invoking dismiss() in the onPostExecute() method.

```
    private class GetPersonList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://myNamespace/myMethod";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "myMethod";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://myNamespace/";
    private static final String URL =
            "http://myURL/myAsmxFile.asmx";

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                "Wait",
                "Retrieving data",
                true
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String finalResult = null;

        //Create request object
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        //Create envelope to which we add our request object
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        //Required for .net
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        //Add the request object to the envelope
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        //Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            //Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            // Get the response
            // Cast as SoapObject and not SoapPrimitive
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

            //Assign it to response to a static variable
            finalResult = response.toString();

            // Now loop through the response (loop through the properties)
            // and add them to the list
            for(int i = 0; i < response.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
                list.add(response.getProperty(i).toString());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("######## ERROR " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return finalResult;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String str) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Returned SOAP XML: " + str);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Set adapter
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, list);

                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have heard that there is another way of doing this using Gson/Json, I will post that once I have figured it out.

Cheerz